# is it possible to use regex to search inside an array using php

Tags: php

I have an array of string i need to search an string inside the array using regex is it possible if so please explain..

Answer (score 9):

```
$a = preg_grep("/search_word/",$array_of_strings);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `foreach` loop to loop through all the elements and use a `preg_match` on each of them. If it matches, add it to an array of matches.

```
foreach($array as $check) {
    if (preg_match("/expression/", $check)) $matches[] = $check;
}
```

Very simple example.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the array using a foreach loop and search for the key in each element. An example:

```
<?php

$days = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday');
$key = "Sunday";

foreach($days as $day) {

    if(preg_match("/$key/",$day)) {
        echo "Key $key found !!";
    }
}
?>
```