# how to find "http" in string from array?

Tags: php, regex, arrays

In PHP I have an array like this:

```
array
  0 => string 'open' (length=4)
  1 => string 'http://www.google.com' (length=21)
  2 => string 'blank' (length=5)
```

but it could also be like:

```
array
  0 => string 'blank' (length=5)
  1 => string 'open' (length=4)
  2 => string 'http://www.google.com' (length=21)
```

now it is easy to find "blank" with `in_array("blank", $array)` but how can I see if one string is starting with "http"?

I've tried with

```
array_search('http', $array); // not working
array_search('http://www.google.com', $array); // is working
```

now everything after `http? could vary (how to write vary, varie? could be different is what I mean!)

Now do I need a regex or how can I check if `http` exists in array string?

Thanks for advices

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354024/is-it-possible-to-use-regex-to-search-inside-an-array-using-php

Comment: How about a foreach loop with strpos?

Comment: And there you [go](https://eval.in/96086), `preg_grep()` to the rescue !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Welcome to PHP, there's a function for that."

Try [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep)

```
preg_grep("/^http\b/i",$array);
```

Regex explained:

```
/^http\b/i
 ^\  / ^ `- Case insensitive match
 | \/  `--- Boundary character
 |  `------ Literal match of http
 `--------- Start of string
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/preg_grep) function which returns an array of entries that match the pattern.

```
$array = array("open", "http://www.google.com", "blank");

$search = preg_grep('/http/', $array);

print_r($search);
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution without regex:

```
$input  = array('open', 'http://www.google.com', 'blank');
$output = array_filter($input, function($item){
  return strpos($item, 'http') === 0;
});
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  1 => string 'http://www.google.com' (length=21)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_grep](http://www.php.net/preg_grep)

```
$match = preg_grep("/http/",$array);
if(!empty($match)) echo "http exist in the array of string.";
```

or you can use [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [preg_match](http://www.php.net/preg_match)

```
foreach($array as $check) {
    if (preg_match("/http/", $check))
    echo "http exist in the array of string.";
}
```

Comment: `preg_match()` in a loop is extremely slow, better use `strpos()` in this case